# log of average or average of logs for regression?

Tags: regression, logarithm, dependent-variable

I have to perform regression for product prices over a period of time and I have to do so for multiple categories. For eg. Category_1 includes prices of item_1, item_2 and item_3 over a period of time, let's say two months. My question is how do I combine/transform these item_1, item_2 and item_3 into one dependent variable?
Should I take the average of the prices of the three items and then take log of the average price or should I take average of the logs of prices of individual items? I went through similar questions but I still don't quite understand what to do.

Edit: I want to use regression to see how an “intervention”
affected a dependent variable measured at discrete time periods.
The dependent variable is the log of prices of Category_1 (Category_1 is the combined prices of item_1, item_2 and item_3, need to find a way to combine these items into one category). Then I have date t and another dummy variable Intervention_t which is equal to one if the intervention was in action on date t, else it is zero.

So basically what I'm trying to do is find out how this intervention affected the prices of Category_1, Category_2, etc. over a period of time. Every category has items of a particular type eg. fruits, veggies, etc. So I have records of retail prices of individual items for a month before the intervention and a month after or during the intervention.

Comment: please explain in the question (not comment) why you are doing the regression and  what are the dependent and independent variables.

Comment: Got it, edited the question. hope it helps now.

Comment: You haven't said what the  *business* problem you are trying to solve is. If you provide that it should be clearer what aggregation to do.  I would assume you would take some log of the weighted average of the prices.  eg weighting by the goods of each item sold.

Comment: Okay, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Why do you want to aggregate at all?

Comment: Because I'm required to do a category-wise analysis to understand how different categories of products are affected by the intervention. And every category has some 3-5 products. And I don't have category-wise data. I have data on retail prices of individual products.